# Equation in C# not calculating, just returns 0

Tags: c#, html, textbox

I am not sure why but this is only returning 0, previously it was giving an error about not being able to convert double to int so I changed the Result var from Int to Double and the error went away.

```
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(InterestDropdown.Text))
    {
        CalculatedPayment.Text = "Please select something for Interest 
        Rate";
    }
    else
        {
        int Loan1, Term1, Interest1;
        Loan1 = Convert.ToInt32(LoanAmount.Text);
        Term1 = Convert.ToInt32(Term.Text);
        Interest1 = InterestDropdown.SelectedIndex;
        Double Result = Loan1 * Interest1 / (1 - Math.Pow(1 + Interest1, 
         (Term1 * 12)));
        CalculatedPayment.Text = Result.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the actual numbers being used at runtime?  Making random changes until "the error goes away" isn't going to get far, but debugging and specifically defining what functionality you want might help.  In particular, if you're performing math between integers and doubles then you could simply be losing a lot of your decimal precision.

Comment: I'll take a wild guess and say that the `InterestDropdown.SelectedIndex` doesnt represent the actual interest rate.  If the first item is picked, its zero.

Comment: In InterestDropdown.SelectedIndex I guess you want to take the value of SelectedIndex. So InterestDropdown.SelectedIndex.Value should be the code. Please mention the asp dropdown control to help us understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using int to represent a double. If Interest1 is less than 1 ie .5 it will be evaluated to 0.

Loan1 * 0 / anything = 0

Change your int if you are using decimal values.